# Why pushing the csv files through spark to HIVE throwing IndexError?

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I am working with Spark 2.1 to push a csv file to the HIVE table that it creates too. But I am getting the error as below

```
df = sqlcontext.read.load(
    "/home/{}/{}/{}/*.csv".format(path, files),
    format='com.databricks.spark.csv',
    header='true',
    inferSchema='true'
)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The corresponding code is given below:

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .master("local")\
        .appName("CSV_to_HIVE")\
        .enableHiveSupport()\
        .getOrCreate()
sqlcontext = SQLContext(spark)

file_list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv', 'file4.csv']
file_path = ['<path_to_the_folder>']

for files in file_list:
    for path in file_path:
        df = sqlcontext.read.load(
            "/home/{}/{}/{}/*.csv".format(path, files),
            format='com.databricks.spark.csv',
            header='true',
            inferSchema='true'
        )
        df.registerTempTable("my_temp_table")
        db_name = 'DB_NAME'
        sqlContext.sql("create table {}.`{}_{}` stored as ORC as select * from my_temp_table".format(db_name, path, files))
```

NOTE: My observations are as below:-

1) In sqlcontext.read.load() has three tuple for the full path to the files. 
2) initially I started with just 2 tuples, but in that case I was getting error as below:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: hdfs://dev-batch-bi/home/home/<path_to>/file1.csv/*.csv;'
```

So from the above error, it is obvious that "/home" shouldn't be the part of the "/"
separated tuples. As well as, the name of the actual csv file is coming before the "/*.csv" which is also wrong. Therefore, no of tuples has to be adjusted to complete the task. I have tried adding 3rd tuple which I have already mentioned earlier in my post. But it is of no use.

Kindly help.

Comment: You didn't pass enough params for your format. `"/home/{}/{}/{}/*.csv".format(path, files)`

Comment: Hadoop allows wildcards, so you should be able to get away with passing the `"/path/to/files`" or `"/path/to/files/*.csv"`. How you construct the path string (with formats or whatever) is up to you. You might want to construct as seperate var and print it before passing to pyspark, so you know if it's correct or not.